# Is there a similar Linq function to XPathEvaluate but for XQuery expressions instead of XPath?

Tags: c#, linq-to-xml, xquery

The Linq to Xml library in .Net has the extension method XPathEvaluate which allows to query an XDocument by passing an XPath expression. But XPath is more restrictive than XQuery. Is there a function XQueryEvaluate ? If this does not exist in the framework, do you know of an external library?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Saxon-HE](http://saxon.sourceforge.net/#F9.3HE) (there is a .net version) or [XQSharp](http://www.xqsharp.com/xqsharp/index.htm) (commercial).